# Why my Windows form application not connecting to mysql in another computer?

Tags: c#

I am here to ask You about the problem I am facing with the windows application we are developing. We have used mysql database for this application and when the .exe file is copied in another system it is not connecting to the database in server system.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciawP.jpg)

This is the connection string we have used

```
string connection = "server=192.168.4.46;database=elog;uid=root;password=miccollege123";
```

The application is running well when run in visual studio. But, not when run through .exe file in another computer.

Hope I'll find a solution within short notice. Link for application error image is also included.

THANK YOU...

Comment: Did you enable access from your host to the mysql server?

Comment: from the error message, you appear to have a missing DLL file. You need to make sure it's deployed with the application into the correct location. Also, please don't use "root" for your applications to log in. It has far too many permissions. Create a user account specifically for the application and give it only the permissions it actually needs. That way, any security problems with the application can do far less damage if exploited.

Comment: Have you copied the *assembly* `My.Sql.Data.dll`?

Comment: So My.Sql.Data.dll should present in every computer in which the application is deployed right?

Comment: yes. And it must be a compatible version, as well. See the duplicate answer.